# Problem book for Haskell course

Tags: textbook, functional-programming, homework

I need a set of problems for beginner Haskell course represented as a problem book or workbook.
Can you help me find any to give them as a homework on weekly basis?
I was able to find only one book in such a sense but in Portuguese. Is there any in English?
Thank you!

Comment: I can't say I'm familiar with any haskell textbooks, but if you haven't seen it before, there's a [list of haskell textbooks](https://wiki.haskell.org/Books#Textbooks) on the haskell wiki.

Comment: @thesecretmaster That's the thing: textbooks, not WORKbooks you can use to prepare handouts in LaTeX and send on email :-( And to vary these tasks by difficulty level, of course.

Comment: Well, there's [this online thing](https://mmhaskell.com/workbook). I mostly haven't seen workbooks since grammar school, so I am not aware of any great resources.  The very first textbook on thesecretmaster's list advertises its many exercises, so that might be one to check out.

Comment: Hutton's [book](https://doi.org/10.1017/CBO9781316784099) has exercises.

Answer (score 1):

Recently I've been reading through Richard Pawson's book on functional programming aimed at A-Level teaching. I teach the subject at A-Level so I'm always on the lookout for good resources. So far (I have read as far as chapter 6) it is the best explanation of FP I have come across. It comes with 60 exercises and an EAD which students can write their answers in. It is available to download here https://community.computingatschool.org.uk/resources/5975/single

Comment: Is it accessible outside of UK teachers?

Comment: @BenI. Yes because as far as I'm aware you don't need to be a UK teacher to get a login for the CAS website.

Comment: I didn't realize that. I've admired CAS for a long time!  I just signed up for a membership :)